# How do I set download URL for an image to firestore database and realtime Database

Tags: android, url, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have implemented the code to upload the user photo to storage and retrieve it to the firestore and realtimeDB. the problem is when I set the imageuri to database :

then I'm (or user) updating a photo to firebase, the URI is successfully updated to the profile string..(firestore) and image srting (realtimeDB). but after some time/after the app closes, the photo not loading properly.(or its gone), it didn't use the firebase token as the download Uri.

its like this :
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A81399

then I attached another code to get the updated image URL from storage. But another problem

for now, Both Databases didn't store the URLs

I have attached the code below.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {


public ProfileFragment() {

}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


CircleImageView profileImageView;
FragmentProfileBinding binding;

private Uri photoUri;
private String imageUrl;


FirebaseFirestore firestore;
FirebaseStorage storage;
FirebaseAuth auth;
StorageReference storageReference;

DocumentReference documentReference;
DatabaseReference DBreference;
String currentUserId;

User user; //class




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();



    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    currentUserId = fUser.getUid();


    documentReference = firestore.collection("Users").document(currentUserId);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Pictures");
    DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");




    update = binding.updateBtn;
   
    profileImageView= binding.profilePhoto;



    clickListener();

    return binding.getRoot();



}

private void clickListener() {

    profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            //noinspection deprecation
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
    });


   
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressDialog.show();



            StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Profile Pictures")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

            reference.putFile(photoUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            imageUrl = uri.toString();

                            updateUserProfileToFirestore();


                            updateUserProfileToDataBase();

                        }
                    });


                }


            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull @NotNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {


                    long totalSi = snapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    long transferS = snapshot.getBytesTransferred();

                    long totalSize = (totalSi / 1024);
                    long transferSize = transferS / 1024;

                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) transferSize) + "KB / " + ((int) totalSize) + "KB");


                }
            });



        }

    });






}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    try {

        if (data.getData() != null) {

            photoUri = data.getData();

         //   profileImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);


        }

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }





}

private void updateUserProfileToFirestore() {


  Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<>();

  profile.put("profile", imageUrl);



    final DocumentReference sDoc = firestore.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
    firestore.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {


        @Override
        public Void apply(@NonNull  Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(sDoc);


            transaction.update(sDoc, profile);

          //  transaction.update(sDoc, "name", binding.nameBox.getText() );

            return null;
        }


    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {


            progressDialog.setMessage("updated!");

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    progressDialog.setMessage("Can't upload");
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to update, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                }
            });


   // final DatabaseReference




}


// Realtime database

private void updateUserProfileToDataBase() {

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("image", imageUrl);

            DBreference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                    .updateChildren(map)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


}
```

}

[image: RealtimeDB]

[image: Firestore]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated, is it okay ??

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo App not crashing.

Comment: Most likely the app closes because of a crash, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo for the first code, yes. and the second time (still) no. in this code

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. There's a lot going on in the code you shared, and there's too many options to consider effectively. If you step through your code in a debugger, and check the values used in each line, and the logcat output coming from that line, what is the place where you first see a  problem. I also highly recommend spending some time reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as isolating the problem is the key to allowing use to effectively help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It's based on the storage reference.  just changed to "reference".

because I already declared the storage reference. but I entered it twice